# SDL Texture not scaling to the renderQuad

Tags: c++, textures, sdl2

I'm building a Space Invaders clone and using a sprite sheet for my invaders, but when I grab the texture from the sprite sheet, it doesn't scale to the renderQuad that I set.

This is the original sprite map - https://i.stack.imgur.com/O70dw.jpg (I'm only using the sprites in the left 2 columns)

This is the output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsaQ2.jpg

This loads in the BMP file

```
bool AnimationManager::loadFromFile()
{
    free();

    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("SpriteSheet.bmp");
    if (loadedSurface == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteSheetW = loadedSurface->w;
        spriteSheetH = loadedSurface->h;
        InvaderSpritemap = loadedSurface;
        loadMedia();
        return InvaderSpritemap != NULL;
    }
}
```

This blits the surface from the spritesheet, this is then converted into a texture

```
SDL_Texture* AnimationManager::getTexture(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int health, int invaderType, int animationState)
{
    SDL_Surface* invaderSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 40, 40, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_Texture* invaderTexture = NULL;

    switch (health)
    {
    case 1:
        SDL_BlitSurface(InvaderSpritemap, &invaderSprites_redHealth[invaderType][animationState], invaderSurface, NULL);
        break;
    case 2:
        SDL_BlitSurface(InvaderSpritemap, &invaderSprites_orangeHealth[invaderType][animationState], invaderSurface, NULL);
        break;
    case 3: 
        SDL_BlitSurface(InvaderSpritemap, &invaderSprites_greenHealth[invaderType][animationState], invaderSurface, NULL);
        break;
    }
    
    invaderTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, invaderSurface);
    return invaderTexture;
}
```

This draws the invaders to the screen.

```
void Invader::draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* text)
{
    SDL_Rect renderQuad;
    renderQuad.x = XPos;
    renderQuad.y = YPos;
    renderQuad.w = Width;
    renderQuad.h = Height;

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, text, NULL, &renderQuad);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the portion that's supposed to be copied from the InvaderSpritemap is correct, so check the data inside invaderSprites_redHealth etc. It looks like you're copying too big portion of the sprite sheet.

Comment: The 3rd argument in `SDL_RenderCopy` defines the source rect that represents the sprite inside the sprite sheet. I noticed that you're passing NULL, but I guess it should contain only the rect of the sprite you want, not the entire sprite sheet size.